# ADB installation failures

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have developed an APK which I would like to install on a Samsung phone. I have downloaded and installed
the Samsung USB driver and I have my phone (a Galaxy Note 9) connected to my Windows 10 computer. I used Android
Studio to develop the software and generate the APK. I am using adb to do the install.

Despite all this, when I attempt to run adb  to do the installation:

```
 adb install -r app.debug.apk
```

I get the following failure:

```
Performing Push Install
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
```

Am I missing something here? How do I get my apk installed onto my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when your device is not connected to your pc.
Check these things -

- Enable USB debugging by going into developer options.
  https://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html
- On your phone, tap the "Charging this device via USB" notification. Under "Use USB for," select File Transfer. (Optional, in case the first one, don't work)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I carried out your suggestions and it still didn't work -- until I searched for USB in my settings. Apparently on a Samsung Galaxy phone you need to also turn USB debugging on in order to enable installation. It is an additional step that was necessary in order to make things work (at least on a Samsung phone).